# Pure CSS solution for a non-conjested, fault-less, perfectly-repitious dotted line using CSS Background Radial-Gradient

Tags: html, css, layout, background, radial-gradients

### A CSS Layout Problem

Currently I'm not happy with my standard `<hr>` dotted lines. The results are far from the holy grail dotted lines I was looking for.

```
hr{
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Black;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

[image]

*Please open image at 100% scaling in a separate window.*

[image] [image] [image]

The dots are too close to each other and I don't want dashed lines with black stripes. I want dots but with more spacing in between them.

### Desire for (and Design of) the Pure Elusive Holy Grail Dotted Line

In my dreams I see in front of me a pure CSS dotted line, like in this image (made in Photoshop).

[image]

*Please open image at 100% scaling in a separate window.*

[image]

A horizontal rule that meets the following criteria:

- A height of 1px
- A repeating pattern of 2 pixels transparent gap followed by a 1 Black pixel
- Has a 100% width (give or take 3 pixels)
- From the first dot till the last dot, at no point are there dots pushed together (black dots too close together) or pulled apart (more than 2 pixels gap spacing in between Black dots)
- A pure CSS layout using CSS Background Radial-Gradient

### Where I'm stuck now

I cannot get this to work properly yet. What have I overlooked and why is the following not working?

```
hr{
background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, Black 100%, Black 100%);
background-position: 0 0, 100% 100%, 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: 3px 1px;
}
```

Until the solution, the search for the elusive holy grail hr remains untackled.

```css
html{ margin: 7em; background: #EEE}
article { background: lightblue; height: 100px; padding: 2em}


hr{
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Black;
    border-top: none;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
    
hr{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, Black 100%, Black 100%);
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 100%, 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 3px 1px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  
  <p> Text   </p>
<hr>

  <p> Text   </p>
</article>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your 'squashed up dots' problem on an hr. Could you create a snippet we can run and tell us what browser/OS/device/viewport size you are on?

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks A Haworth for your comment. To answer your comment: 1) Win 64 Pro / Chrome 103 Full HD.  2) Quetsion completely overhauled, detailed, refined and updated 3) Code snippet added of both the old standard and the new non working method.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. Although I have no idea why and how precisely. Other more elegant answers, improvements and suggestions are welcome that can further explain the workings of the magic here.

After many trials I have figured out that the first number represents the gap size and the second number represents the dot width in `background-size: 3px 1px;`

```
hr{
    border: none;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, Black 100%, Transparent 100%);
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 3px 1px; // GAP width and DOT width
    height: 1px;
    }
```

```css
html{ margin: 4em; background: #EEE}
article { background: lightblue; height: 100px; padding: 2em}

hr{
    border: none;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, Black 100%, Transparent 100%);
    background-position: 0 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 3px 1px;  /* First Nr is the GAP width, second Nr is the DOT width */
    height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<article>
<p>Text</p>
<hr>
<p>Text</p>
</article>
```